# How do I call an external method with JQuery validate to check zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NP8sS/1005/) that validates a zip code with min and max length of 5. But now I want to check with my server or with google maps that the zip code is good! How do I add a remote method to the validate options, where it's called when the 5th number is entered?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#contact").validate({
    //onkeyup: function(element) { // does not work/get called
     // return false;
     // if (element.length == 5) {
        //return false;
      //}
    //},
    rules: {
      "zip-code": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 5
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "zip-code": {
        required: "Please, enter a value",
        minlength: "5 char minimum",
        maxlength: "5 char max"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#docs {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="zip-code">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="required input-xlarge" id="zip-code" name="zip-code" value="" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

Comment: Which method are you intending to call? You should call this validation method by ajax. Is this your question?

Comment: I just want to call any method. I don't know the syntax! or where in the code to put it. I tried onkeyup and remote but nothing seems to work. Essentially, when a 5th number is entered I want to call a method that makes a call to my server or google maps to test if the zip code is valid.